# How can i get class parameters of class file

Tags: java, jsystem

I want to read parameters of a class after compilation. I only need the names.

For example:

```
public class X {
   public String y;
   ...
}
```

I want to compile the code to a class file. Then have another java project read the names of classes in this case `X` and all of class's parameters in this case `y`.

Can i do it?
If its possible, are the parameters have to be public?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use JSystem - an automation framework in java.
To do it, do I need to read a class file and read all the class names and those parameters? I hope its understandable.

For people who know JSystem, I tried to make JRunner but web gui(with spring).

Comment: Please consider telling us more details of what you're trying to do (not 100% clear to me) and more importantly, about your motivation behind your request. I can't help wondering if this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in disguise.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSystem, but it sounds like what you're trying to do is what's called "reflection".  Searching for that term might point you in the right direction.

Comment: yes, I try reflection but for class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use java reflection. The following code will give you all classes in a package:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

 Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Then to get the properties of a class you can do the following:

```
 for (Field f : getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    System.out.println("Field: " + f);
  }
```